Ctrl+Shift+Right to select the word only (no whitespace)
It drives me crazy trying to select whole words without whitespace. Ctrl+Shift+Left, when at the end of a word, will select the full word. But Ctrl+Shift+Right, at the beginning of a word, will select not just the word but the whitespace between it and the next word.
I understand why, as Ctrl+ Left/Right jumps to the beginning of each word, but when holding Shift, I can't imagine why you would want the whitespace.
In my work I often need to copy some text that is formatted as tab-delimitted, except the tabs are spaces, so if I press Ctrl+Shift+Right I have to then press Left several times each time to remove the whitespace.
Is there any way to change this behavior? Something like Hotkeycontrol or Powertoys can't do it. I can't be the only one who'd like to change this.

Please edit your question and add mention the app(s) where this behaviour happens.

Ctrl + Right goes to just before the next word, it's the attended behaviour.

@Reddy, it happens in all apps, as it's system-level.
@ Toto, being the expected behavior does not mean it's ideal

Upon further Googling I found a ton of people complaining about this behavior, so I created a solution.
Here's an AutoHotKey script I made to set Ctrl+Shift+C to copy selected text without extra whitespace.
https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=132871
^+c::  ; Ctrl+Shift+C hotkey
{
    ; Save the current clipboard content
    ClipboardBackup := ClipboardAll()

    ; Clear the clipboard to prepare for copying
    A_Clipboard := ""

    ; Send Ctrl+C to copy the selected text
    SendInput("^c")

    ; Wait for the clipboard to contain text (maximum wait time is 0.5 seconds)
    if (ClipWait(0.5)) {
        ; Trim whitespace from the clipboard content
        A_Clipboard := Trim(A_Clipboard)
    } else {
        ; Restore the original clipboard content if needed
        Clipboard := ClipboardBackup
    }

    ; Release the backup variable to free memory
    ClipboardBackup := ""
    
    return
}

Before I figured that out, I had written a Firefox addon to do the same, just in-browser, but with AHK it's not needed.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ctrl-shift-c-copy-trimmed/
I had also found that in Firefox there is a setting,
layout.word_select.eat_space_to_next_word = false

to limit the selection to the word, without whitespace, when double-clicking or pressing Ctrl+Shift+Right. Access it via the URL about:config
